# Return number less than or equal to with a limit of 5 using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery which returns if the **number** is less than or equal to the **selectedyear**

```
return parseInt(number, 10) <= selectedyear;
```

I want to keep this functionality but limit the less than to only 5 deep.

e.g.1). If the **number** was 10 I would want all numbers less than 10 - but only the first 5 values. e.g 10,9,8,7,6

e.g.2). If the **number** was 22 I would want all numbers less than 22 - but only the first 5 values. e.g 22,21,20,19,18

Not sure if this is even possible - or there is an easier way around this.

Comment: can you show the full function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function accepting both the number to check and the limit for the comparison.

If `num` is lower or equal to `limit` and `num` is greater than `limit - 5` then return true

```
function isInRange(num, limit) {
   return (num <= limit) && (num > limit - 5);
}

if (isInRange(number, selectedYear)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for the function to only return on the first 5 values (i.e. return only after its been called 5 times)?

Comment: Yes, Basically I don't want every number less than say 16 - I only want the 5 numbers less than and including 16 - which would be 16,15,14,13,12. Really hard to explain, sorry about that.